# MongooseJS not saving array correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am having trouble with mongoosejs, I think.  I am trying to keep an array of objects at a specific size of 2.  When this function is called it adds an item to the array and slims it down if necessary. However when I save the array the size is not trimmed down to 2.  Follow the code and comments.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
 user.location.push(req.body);  //Add a new object to the array.

    if(user.location.length > 2)  //If the array is larger than 2
      user.location.splice(0,1);   //Remove the first item

    console.log(user.location);  //This outputs exactly what I would expect.

    user.save(function(err, updatedUser){
      if(err)
        next(new Error('Could not save the updated user.'));
      else { 
        res.send(updatedUser);  //This outputs the array as if it was never spliced with a size greater than 2.
      }
    });
```

Comment: How is `location` defined in your schema?

Comment: just as an array "location: []"

Answer (score 8):

Because you're defining `location: []` in your schema, Mongoose treats that field as `Mixed` which means you have to notify Mongoose when you've changed it.  See the docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

Change your code that updates `user.location` to be:

```
if(user.location.length > 2) {
  user.location.splice(0,1);
  user.markModified('location');
}
```

Comment: This seems like it should have worked, but didn't.  Any other ideas, or maybe this was just part of the problem.  If I actually remove the first array in the element and save, then add an element to the array  and save, it works 100% of the time.

Comment: object.markModified('objec_array_property') Worked for me.